# How to run component's method via HTML in Vue2

Tags: javascript, html, methods, vue.js, components

I have a .vue file, `ServiceList`, which imports the component `Information.vue`. I would like to run `Information`'s code in a loop in `ServiceList`'s template like so:

```
ServiceList.vue

<template>
  <div> 
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <div v-for="service in services">
      <h2>{{ service.name }}</h2>
      <information v-bind:service="service"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Information from './Information'
... (more components here)

export default {
  components: {
    Information,
    ... (more components here)
  },
  ... (rest of export here)
}

</script>
```

This is what `Information` looks like:

```
Information.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <p v-bind:id="'info'+service.id"/>      
  </div>  
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props:['service'],
  data: function () {
    return {
        services: this.$store.state.Services.data
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getInfo: function (service) {
        var info = '<b>Servicename:</b> <br>';
        info += service.name;

        ... (method adds more to 'info' here)

        document.getElementById('info'+service.id).innerHTML = info;
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I have tried to do stuff like

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-bind:id="'info'+service.id"/>  
    {{ getInfo(service) }}  
  </div>  
</template>
```

but it never seems to work. Weird thing is that when I make it a button,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getInfo(service)">GET INFO</button> 
    <p v-bind:id="'info'+service.id"/>
  </div>  
</template>
```

it works perfectly! But I don't want a button, I just want it to appear.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: why are you generating `HTML` in `getInfo`, just use `vue` template to do it

Comment: I suspect the method IS actually running (you can test with a console.log) but at the moment the bind for the <p> didn't happen yet, so the getElementById is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate DOM in Vue js for such trivial case, just add all you want to template and remove `getInfo` method, example:

```
Information.vue

<template>
   <div>
     <p>
       <b>Servicename:</b> <br>
       {{ service.name }}<br>
       <b>Another Field:</b> <br>
       {{ service.anotherField }}<br>
       <b>Another Field 2 :</b> <br>
       {{ service.anotherField2 }}<br>
     </p>      
   </div>  
</template>
```

**OR** if you *really* want to work with html do this:

```
Information.vue

<template>
   <div>
     <p v-html="getInfo(service)"/>      
   </div>  
</template>

<script>

 export default {
    props:['service'],
    data: function () {
       return {
         services: this.$store.state.Services.data
       }
    },
    methods: {
      getInfo: function (service) {
          if (!service) return '';
          var info = '<b>Servicename:</b> <br>';
          info += service.name;

          ... (method adds more to 'info' here)

          return info;
     }
   }
 }
```